# How do I convert this piece of JSP code to Thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

```
 <c:forEach items="${categories}" var="category">
    <a href="#" >${category.name}</a>
 </c:forEach>
```

I want to change it to thymeleaf and I am kind of new to thymeleaf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `th:block` (`th:block` is simply an attribute container that allows template developers to specify whichever attributes they want which will be removed after the attributes are executed) along with the `th:each` attribute for iteration similar to the `c:forEach` tag used in JSPs.

```
<th:block th:each="category : ${categories}">
<a href="#" th:text="${category.name}"></a>
</th:block>
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a th:block in this case.  You should put the `th:each` directly on your `a` tag.  Like this:

```html
<a href="#" th:each="category : ${categories}" th:text="${category.name}" />
```

Comment: Looking back at this, I just noticed this answer. This is indeed the better approach here.